# How can I make a dictionary, with keys, from an array and list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two collections:

```
      List<string> files =
            Directory.GetFiles(FilePath).ToList().Select(file => new FileInfo(file).Name).ToList();

        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(FilePath);
```

However, I'd like to add both of these to an empty dictionary, so I have a large dictionary with paths and files. The thing I am not sure of, how/where do I specify the keys?

For files, I want the filename as the key, and for the directories, I want the last directory (e.g. c in a/b/c) to be the key. I know how to get this information with FileInfo/DirectoryInfo classes, but not sure how to include this in creating a dictionary from the above?

I'm using .NET V3.5 and LINQ is fine.

Thanks

Comment: You've told us what you want the keys to be, but what about the values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For files, you can do

```
var  filesDictonary = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath)
                                      .Select(file => new FileInfo(file))
                                      .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f);
```

for directories,

```
var directoriesDictonary = Directory.GetDirectories(FilePath)
                                     .Select(d  => new DirectoryInfo(d))
                                     .ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d);
```

Comment: I think that'd work. The last bit (the f after the argument), prevents the code from compiling.

Comment: That should do what I need as I can get the fullname (or name) from the dictionary. Both fileinfo and directoryinfo derive from the same base type so the members are the same. The only thing I'd change is to get a dictionary with the filename/directory name as the key and the entire path as the value? How could I do that with the above?

Comment: @dotnetdev are you trying to have one dictionary with both filename and directory names as keys and FileSystemInfo (the base class) instance as values ? If so, in select, you can cast they like this `file => (FileSystemInfo) new FileInfo(file)` and you can `Union()` the two dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the information you need, and you know how to pair it up properly.  You just use this statement to add it to the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict.Add(file, directory);
```

Unless I'm not understanding you? Are you asking how to add them?  Or how to pair the file with the directory properly?

Answer (score 0):

So far I like **Bala R**'s LINQ answer best (and he's got my upvote), but it's worth mentioning that in a general case, when you want to combine a `List<string>` and a `string[]` into a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you can always go with a basic `for` loop:

```
var MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(MyList.Count, MyArray.Length); i++)
{
    MyDictionary.Add(MyList[i], MyArray[i]);
}
```

It might be a little boring, but it'll work for any pair of `IEnumerable<T>` collections.